# Unity Server Initialization Fails (LAN)

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

So I'm learning to network with Unity, and after reading some documentation and looking at an example, I ended up with the code below. Whenever I run the program (Using Build & Run) and press the button to host a server, I get the message "Initializing..." but it never says "Server Ready:  players connected.". To me that means that the server is failing to intialize somehow, but I really don't know. Other stuff: Even while it says "Initializing..." I can mouse over the other buttons and click on them so the program isn't frozen. Also, the first time I ran it I had to give it permission to go through my firewall, which I did. I'm only trying to get this to work over LAN, I don't care about going over the internet with this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class NetworkTestScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private string Address = "127.0.0.1";
    private int PlayerCount = 0;
    private float NextUpdate = 0.0F;

    public NetworkPlayer Player;
    public float UpdateInterval = 0.1F;

    public GameObject Canvas;
    public Text[] Texts;

    void Start()
    {

        Canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
        Texts = Canvas.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();

        IPHostEntry Host;
        Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach(IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList)
        {

            if(IP.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {

                Address = IP.ToString();

            }

        }

    }

    void Update()
    {

        if(Network.isClient && Time.realtimeSinceStartup > NextUpdate)
        {

            NextUpdate = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + UpdateInterval;

            //If there is input, send it in RPC to server, which then sends it as an RPC to other players

        }

    }

    public void StartServer()
    {

        Network.InitializeServer(2, 25000, false);

        Texts[2].text = "Initializing...";

    }

    public void Connect()
    {

        Network.Connect(Address, 25000);
        Texts[3].text = "Connecting...";

    }

    void OnConnectedToServer()
    {

        Texts[3].text = "Connected.";
        Debug.Log("Connected to server.");

    }

    void OnFailedToConnect(NetworkConnectionError Error)
    {

        Texts[3].text = "Connection failed.";
        Debug.Log("Connection failed: " + Error);

    }

    void OnSeverInitialized()
    {

        Debug.Log("Server initialized.");

        Texts[2].text = "Server Ready: " + PlayerCount + " players connected.";

    }

    void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer P)
    {

        PlayerCount++;
        NetworkViewID ViewID = Network.AllocateViewID();
        Texts[2].text = "Server Ready: " + PlayerCount + " players connected.";

        if(PlayerCount == 2)
        {

            Texts[2].text = "Players ready. Starting...";

        }

        Debug.Log("Player " + ViewID.ToString() + " connected from " + P.ipAddress + ":" + P.port);

    }

    void OnPlayerDisconnected(NetworkPlayer P)
    {

        PlayerCount--;
        Texts[2].text = "Server Ready: " + PlayerCount + " players connected.";

        Debug.Log("Player disconnected: " + P.ToString());

        //Halt game

    }

}
```

Comment: I have an online and LAN multiplayer [reference Unity game on GitHub, called Radius](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/Radius) - The [Network](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/Radius/blob/master/Radius/Assets/Scripts/Managers/NetworkManager.cs) and [LAN](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/Radius/blob/master/Radius/Assets/Scripts/Managers/LANManager.cs) manager would probably be useful to you.

Comment: maybe changing more port number can solve problem. I recommend give port number higher then 25000, i generally use test: 27017 etc.